# jquery Fade In Module Window

Tags: jquery

First of all, I want to express my appreciation for considering my question. Thank you for looking at my question. I'm grateful for your time in trying to help me!

What I'm trying to create (using jQuery) is: a small window that asks for the visitor's email. That is, the user is looking at the page, reading along...and then about 30 seconds later, this box appears (fades in or something aesthetic) that asks if they would like to sign up on my email list.

Then they can input their email (or click "close" to close the pop up window if they decline).

I see this on other websites a lot, but can't figure out how to recreate it on my own. I've tried!

This is what I have right now:
http://halloweenseattle.com/faq_test.php

After 2 seconds, the box appears. But it moves the text down (and then back up again when it closes - that looks funny). And I'd like the box to sit **on top of** the page (so it has focus).

Thank you very much for your time!
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your page, you will want to set the box to use `position:fixed`. This will cause it to "float" above all the text. After that, its just a matter of positioning it where you want on the screen. Here is where you should put it:

```
#loginmodal {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  ... etc ...
  position: fixed;
}
```